# How to save files inside/within the app in a non-sandbox app?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm aware of storing files as the below:

In a non-sandboxed Mac app:. `/Users/username/Documents`.

In a sandboxed app: `/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.YourApp/Documents`

However, I'm writing an app that needs to save files locally/inside the app whilst acting as a non-sandbox app.

How can I save downloaded/copied files to `/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.YourApp/Documents`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the application support folder:

```
/Users/name/Library/Application Support/com.yourcompany.YourApp/...
```

The app needs to create its own folder in Application Support. Use [`URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory) to locate this folder.